# how to match json data with different scenarios in Specflow c#

Tags: c#, api, automation, specflow

I am using Specflow with c# and need help for API automation testing
I have different scenarios like
Scenario outline: senario1
Given There is coffee
And I added syrup

Scenario outline: senario2
Given There is  coffee
And I added syrup
And have mentioned the json file name in examples

And I have stored query parameters in one json file.

```
{
"scenario1":
      {
       "businesscontext": "1",
        "Userid": "123"
      },
"scenario2":
      {
       "Searchstring": "abc"
      }
}
```

How can I access this scenario specific json data in Given and pass it to endpoint as query parameters